# Meaning of draft

Tags: meaning-in-context, context

The following is an excerpt from a book:

> The article “Poll Finds Most Oppose return to Draft,
>   wouldn’t encourage Children to enlist” (Associated Press,
>   December 18, 2005) reports that in a random sample of 1,000
>   American adults, 430 answered yes to the following question:
>   “If the military draft were reinstated, would you favor drafting
>   women as well as men?” The data were used to test `H0: p=0.5`
>   versus `Ha:p<0.5`, and the null hypothesis was rejected.

What's the meaning of the word `draft` in this context?

Comment: Have you looked in any dictionaries?

Comment: Yeah, I already did. Most of them show examples like "drafting a letter", "bank draft" and so on.

Comment: Sometimes you have to look at all the meanings (scroll down) or use more than one. Cambridge, Collins, Merriam-Webster, Longman, Lexico (Oxford), even Google's search all have the meaning.

Comment: The term *military draft* is in your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In US English, the noun 'draft' can mean 'government scheme of conscription for military service'. When the draft was in operation, all males over 18 had to register with the government, and could be made to report for enrolment in the military armed services. It is also a verb:

> 3. VERB [usually passive]
>      If you are drafted, you are ordered to serve in the armed forces, usually for a limited period of time. [mainly US]

[Draft (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/draft)

Comment: I still don't get the meaning of **return to Draft** in the above sentence

Comment: The text you quoted was a newspaper story headline. These often omit unnecessary words, including articles. Consider it to mean "[A] Poll Finds Most [People] Oppose [a] return to [the] Draft". The draft was in the past, e.g. during the Vietnam war. To have a return to the draft would be to bring it back. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: It means to reinstate the govt. policy of conscription, which was abandoned many years ago.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Phil , I got it now, thanks